# What kind of distribution is this and how can it be approximated to a continuous one?

Tags: probability-distributions

$p(x) = e^{-x\beta}(1-e^{-\beta})$
Where $x$ is integer takinng values as $x = \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ and $\beta > 0 $ is a real constant.

Is this a Poissonian distribution? and how could I approximate it in order to sample continuous random variables.

I have tried to google distributions similar to this but I haven't found anything similar so I'm confused on how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $x$ integer valued?  Your function doesn't integrate to $1$ (for any value of $\beta$) but it sums to $1$ if you assume $x=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$

Comment: Now that you know it is a geometric random variable, is your objective of simulation still the same, and what would you like to do ?

Comment: @lulu It is what I have assumed instinctively.

Comment: @JeanMarie  Sure.  It makes sense, and it does give an actual probability distribution.  But, really, the OP should specify that.  If, to the contrary, the OP simply expects to multiply this by a constant to get it to integrate to $1$ then you'll just get the standard (continuous) exponential distribution.

Comment: The continuous analogue of the geometric is the exponential(considered as the waiting time for the first arrival)    as is the gamma for the negative binomial.

Comment: @lulu, as the OP says "discrete variable", an intermediate step would to gain a degree of freedom by introducing a constant $n$ and saying that $X$ can take all values of the form $k/n$... And, later on make $n$ arbitrarily large? But you, the OP, what is your opinion about all this ?

Comment: @lulu In a dual way, one could set $\beta=\gamma/n$, for a fixed $n$. And then take $n$ arbitrarily large.

Comment: @JeanMarie  I think, whichever way you look at it, the exponential distribution really is the best continuous analog of a geometric distribution.  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93098/how-does-a-geometric-distribution-converge-to-an-exponential-distribution) is a relevant discussion.  But, I repeat, absent word from the OP we are really just guessing at what is desired.

Comment: Yes x is integer taking values as x = {0, 1, 2, ...} The thing is that for the simulation I'm running, for certain values of $\beta$ using the discrete version of the inverse transform sampling, it can be pretty slow because x gets quite large. So I'm thinking that with a continuous approximation I could sample values much faster.

Comment: @lulu Your assumption is right, sorry I didn't specify that, so x is an integer variable that can take values as you said. I believe that you, JeanMarie and theoGR are correct, it is a geometric distribution, the simulations with an exponential distribution seem to be working as expected. Thank you very much for your input lulu, JeanMarie and theoGR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written under the form

$$P(X=k)= e^{-k\beta}(1-e^{-\beta})$$

it's clearly a  **geometrical distribution**

$$P(X=k)= p^{k}(1-p)$$

with $p:=e^{-\beta}$, $p < 1$ because $\beta > 0$.